# jQuery left and right assignment

Tags: jquery

I am tring to decrease and after increase the value of a variable but I got an error.

```
.children('#collapse' + (--count++))
```

The error is:

```
Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

The goal of my code should be to concatenate the decreased count variable and after increase is value

Comment: @Tushar That will also give the same error. That is very much equals to `(count = count-1)++`

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve? You probably have a severe case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `comma` operator at this context,

```
.children('#collapse' + (--count, count++))
```

The syntax that you are using is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is to just subtract 1 from the variable without changing the variable's value. If so, why not just do that?

```
.children('#collapse' + (count - 1))
```